# Why is my Database Size Query Returning Null?

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have SQL Server hosted in Azure and I'm connected with Azure Data Studio.

I run the query shown below (recommended query) and get nulls returned for every database on the server. Am I missing something?

```
with fs as
(
    select database_id, type, size * 8.0 / 1024 size
    from sys.master_files
)
select top 10
    name,
    (select sum(size) from fs where type = 0 and fs.database_id = db.database_id) DataFileSizeMB,
    (select sum(size) from fs where type = 1 and fs.database_id = db.database_id) LogFileSizeMB
from 
    sys.databases db
order by 
    DataFileSizeMB desc
```

I only see results as shown in this screenshot:

[image: Results]

Comment: Have you checked the login you're using has sufficient permissions.

Comment: you have some where from the files which might affect the query. what happen if you run: `select * from sys.master_files`

Comment: _The minimum permissions that are required to see the corresponding row are CREATE DATABASE, ALTER ANY DATABASE, or VIEW ANY DEFINITION._ Ref: [sys.master_files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-master-files-transact-sql) Do you have those permissions?

Answer (score 0):

As per [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-master-files-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#permissions), the user should have the minimum permissions that are required to see the corresponding row: `CREATE DATABASE`, `ALTER ANY DATABASE`, or `VIEW ANY DEFINITION`.

To add the above permissions, use the command below:

```
use master
grant ALTER ANY DATABASE to <user>
grant VIEW ANY DEFINITION to <user>
grant CREATE ANY DATABASE to <user>
```

[image]

Then you will be able to get the database size as shown below:

```
| name   | DataFileSizeMB | LogFileSizeMB |
| ------ | -------------- | ------------- |
|    db  | 392.000000     | 392.000000    |
| tempdb | 64.000000      | 8.000000      |
| msdb   | 19.687500      | 28.812500     |
```